# Получения данных списка, vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Я решил сделать перебор статей используя vue. В общем суть такова, у меня не работало dropdown bootstrap в самом vue, и я скачал дополнения 
(vue-js-dropdown). 
Вот как получилось у меня:

```
<a v-dropdown:select><i class="material-icons" >&#xE8FE; Упорядочить</i></a>

    <dropdown name="select" class="list-group" >

        <a href="#" class="list-group-item disabled">Сначало старые</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Сначало новые</a>

    </dropdown>
```

Фото:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос, мне нужно чтобы нажимали на **"Сначало новые"**, я получал текст этот "**Сначало новые**", и автоматически `"disabled"` добавлялся к нему. А в **"сначало старые"** убирался `disabled` само собой,а потом наоборот. Как я могу такое реализовать во vue?
Использую vue, а не jquery - ибо надо без обновления страницы, да и в jquery такое геморойно делать

Comment: Следует исправить компонент, иначе - никак. Выложите сюда этот компонент.

Comment: Можно использовать флаг, и исходя из его значения управлять свойством `disabled`.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно как-то так. Если правильно понял мысль

```
<template>
    <ul id="dropdown-exp">
        <li v-for="(item, index) in list" :key="index" :class="['list-group-item', item.disabled ? 'disabled' : '']">
            <a href="#" v-on:click.prevent="handleClick($event, index)">{{item.name}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'dropdown',
    data() {
        return {
            list: [{
                name: 'Item 1',
                disabled: false
            },{
                name: 'Item 2',
                disabled: false
            },{
                name: 'Item 3',
                disabled: false
            },{
                name: 'Item 4',
                disabled: false
            },{
                name: 'Item 5',
                disabled: false
            },{
                name: 'Item 6',
                disabled: false
            }]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        handleClick(event, index) {
            if(this.list[index].disabled === true) {
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }

            this.resetDisabled();
            let item = Object.assign({}, this.list[index]);
            item.disabled = true;
            this.list.splice(index, 1);
            this.list.unshift(item);
        },
        resetDisabled() {
            this.list.forEach((item) => {
                item.disabled = false;
            });
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style>
    #dropdown-exp li {
        display: block;
    }

    #dropdown-exp li + li {
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    li.disabled a {
        color: #ccc;
        cursor: not-allowed;
    }
</style>
```